# Subset of a scheme where a section vanishes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose $(X,\mathscr{O})$ is a scheme, $s\in \mathscr{O}(U)$. I am trying to prove that $\{x\in U: s_x=0\in \mathscr{O}_x(\text{the stalk})\}$ is open in $U$ but not necessarily closed. I can see why it's open, but why is it not necessarily closed? Is there any example?

Comment: you could probably take some skyscraper sheaf

Comment: I am actually not familiar with skyscraper sheaf, is there more guidance on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=k[x,y]/(y^2,xy)$ for a field $k$, and set $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$. Then $y\in\mathcal{O}_X(X)=A$ is a section which is zero in the stalk at every point in $D(x)$, but is not zero in the stalk at the origin. As $D(x)$ is open but not closed, this does the trick.

Comment: What is the definition of $D(x)$?

Comment: The open set of points $p$ where $x_p\notin \mathfrak{m}_p$ - equivalently, the locus where the image of $f$ in the residue field is nonzero.

Comment: Can you also explain why it's not zero in the stalk at the origin?

Comment: The stalk at the origin is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y^2,xy)_{(x,y)}$. To say that $y=0$ in this localization means that there exists some element $u$ in $k[x,y]\setminus (x,y)$ so that $uy\in (y^2,xy)$. But this is impossible, as every such $u$ has nonzero constant term.

Comment: How do you see that $D(x)$ is open but not closed? I can see it's open, but why it's not closed?

Comment: If it were closed, our space would be reducible: you could write it as $D(x)\cup V(x)$. But the underlying topological space is the same as the underlying topological space of $\Bbb A^1_k$, which is irreducible. A semi-related suggestion: I don't mind answering follow-up questions in the comments (within reason), but I would much prefer it if you could provide some sort of context in your question that indicated your level and that you're looking for a more explicit solution. This could save you and folks answering your question some back-and-forth in the future - please consider it!